# I have multiple XML files in a folder and i have to insert the data of the files in a database only using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, backend

The script only inserts the first occurence within  of my xml file but i want it to take all the file before it goes to the next file.

```sql
DECLARE @XMLData XML
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XMLFilePath NVARCHAR(255)


DECLARE @FolderPath NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ReportHeader NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ReportTitle NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ReportType NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @REPORT_DATE NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @QUERY_ID NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @NO_OF_FACILITIES NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @BILLED NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @EntityCode NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @EntityType NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @EntityName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @EntityOtherName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DOB NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Gender NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ResidentFlag NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @CountryCode NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PassportNo NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Address1 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Address2 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Address3 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Address4 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Address5 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @CreditType NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @UniqueRefID NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @BorrowerType NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SectorLoanClass NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DateApproved NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Currency NVARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @AmountOrg NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @AmountOut NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @AmountDis NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DateUpdate NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @AmountInst NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DateFirstInst NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Periodicity NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DateLastInst NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DateExp NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DateRegistered NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @NoInst INT
DECLARE @EffectiveDate NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @BalDefault NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @AmountArrs NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @NoOfDays INT
DECLARE @FirstColl NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SecondColl NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ThirdColl NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ForthColl NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @FifthColl NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Remarks NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DateRegularised NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @ActionTaken NVARCHAR(155)
DECLARE @ActionDate NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory1 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory2 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory3 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory4 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory5 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory6 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory7 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory8 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory9 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory10 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory11 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory12 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory13 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory14 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory15 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory16 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory17 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory18 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory19 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory20 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory21 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory22 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory23 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory24 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory25 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory26 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory27 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory28 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory29 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory30 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory31 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory32 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory33 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory34 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory35 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @PaymentHistory36 NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @CurrencyCode NVARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @CurrencyDesc NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @OriginalAmount NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @OutstandingAmount NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @AmountDisbursed NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @BalanceDefault NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @AmountArrears NVARCHAR(255)




-- Specify the folder path containing the XML files

DECLARE @FileList TABLE (XMLFilePath NVARCHAR(255))

SET @FolderPath = 'C:\Users\Ethan\Documents\RC\project1\XML\27920221049718\XML_Extracts'
INSERT INTO @FileList (XMLFilePath)
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir "C:\Users\Ethan\Documents\RC\project1\XML\27920221049718\XML_Extracts\*.xml" /B'

DECLARE XMLFilesCursor CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT XMLFilePath
FROM @FileList

OPEN XMLFilesCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM XMLFilesCursor INTO @XMLFilePath

-- Process each XML file
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN



            -- Load the XML data from the file
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT @XMLData = T.MY_XML
            FROM (
                SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS XML) AS MY_XML
                FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ' + QUOTENAME(@FolderPath + '\' + @XMLFilePath, '''') + ', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)
            ) AS T
            CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes(''/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES'') AS MY_XML(FACILITIES)'


        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XMLData XML OUTPUT', @XMLData OUTPUT



    -- Extract data from the XML and insert into tables
    SET @ReportHeader = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/REPORT_HEADER)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @ReportTitle = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/REPORT_TITLE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @ReportType = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/REPORT_TYPE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')

    SET @EntityCode = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ENTITY_CODE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @EntityType = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ENTITY_TYPE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @EntityName = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ENTITY_NAME)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @EntityOtherName = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ENTITY_OTHER_NAME)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DOB = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DOB)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Gender = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/GENDER)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @ResidentFlag = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/RESIDENT_FLAG)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @CountryCode = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/COUNTRY_CODE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PassportNo = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PASSPORT_NO)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Address1 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ADDRESS1)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Address2 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ADDRESS2)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Address3 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ADDRESS3)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Address4 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ADDRESS4)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Address5 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ADDRESS5)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @CreditType = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/CREDIT_TYPE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @UniqueRefID = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/UNIQUE_REF_ID)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @BorrowerType = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/BORROWER_TYPE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @SectorLoanClass = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/SECTOR_LOAN_CLASS)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DateApproved = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_APPROVED)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Currency = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/CURR)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(3)')
    SET @AmountOrg = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/AMOUNT_ORG)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @AmountOut = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/AMOUNT_OUT)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @AmountDis = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/AMOUNT_DIS)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DateUpdate = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_UPDATE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @AmountInst = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/AMOUNT_INST)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DateFirstInst = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_FIRST_INST)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Periodicity = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PERIODICITY)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DateLastInst = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_LAST_INST)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DateExp = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_EXP)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @DateRegistered = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_REGISTERED)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @NoInst = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/NO_INST)[1]', 'INT')
    SET @EffectiveDate = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/EFFECTIVE_DATE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @BalDefault = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/BAL_DEFAULT)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @AmountArrs = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/AMOUNT_ARRS)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @NoOfDays = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/NO_OF_DAYS)[1]', 'INT')
    SET @FirstColl = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/FIRST_COLL)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @SecondColl = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/SECOND_COLL)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @ThirdColl = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/THIRD_COLL)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @ForthColl = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/FORTH_COLL)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @FifthColl = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/FIFTH_COLL)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @Remarks = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/REMARKS)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    SET @DateRegularised = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/DATE_REGULARISED)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @ActionTaken = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ACTION_TAKEN)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(155)')
    SET @ActionDate = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/ACTION_DATE)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory1 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_1)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory2 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_2)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory3 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_3)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory4 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_4)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory5 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_5)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory6 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_6)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory7 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_7)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory8 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_8)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory9 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_9)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory10 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_10)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory11 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_11)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory12 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_12)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory13 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_13)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory14 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_14)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory15 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_15)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory16 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_16)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory17 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_17)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory18 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_18)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory19 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_19)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory20 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_20)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory21 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_21)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory22 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_22)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory23 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_23)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory24 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_24)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory25 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_25)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory26 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_26)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory27 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_27)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory28 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_28)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory29 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_29)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory30 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_30)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory31 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_31)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory32 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_32)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory33 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_33)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory34 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_34)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory35 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_35)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
    SET @PaymentHistory36 = @XMLData.value('(/MAIN/CPR/FACILITIES/PAYMENT_HISTORY_36)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')
   

    -- Insert the values into the target table
    INSERT INTO XML(EntityCode,EntityType, EntityName,EntityOtherName, DOB, Gender, ResidentFlag,CountryCode,PassportNo, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, CreditType, UniqueRefID, BorrowerType, SectorLoanClass, DateApproved, Currency, AmountOrg, AmountOut, AmountDis, DateUpdate, AmountInst, DateFirstInst, Periodicity, DateLastInst, DateExp, DateRegistered, NoInst, EffectiveDate, BalDefault, AmountArrs, NoOfDays, FirstColl, SecondColl, ThirdColl, FourthColl, FifthColl, Remarks, DateRegularised, ActionTaken, ActionDate, PaymentHistory1, PaymentHistory2, PaymentHistory3, PaymentHistory4, PaymentHistory5, PaymentHistory6, PaymentHistory7, PaymentHistory8, PaymentHistory9, PaymentHistory10, PaymentHistory11, PaymentHistory12, PaymentHistory13, PaymentHistory14, PaymentHistory15, PaymentHistory16, PaymentHistory17, PaymentHistory18, PaymentHistory19, PaymentHistory20, PaymentHistory21, PaymentHistory22, PaymentHistory23, PaymentHistory24, PaymentHistory25, PaymentHistory26, PaymentHistory27, PaymentHistory28, PaymentHistory29, PaymentHistory30, PaymentHistory31, PaymentHistory32, PaymentHistory33, PaymentHistory34, PaymentHistory35, PaymentHistory36, XML_PATH)
    VALUES (@EntityCode,@EntityType,@EntityName,@EntityOtherName, @DOB, @Gender, @ResidentFlag,@CountryCode,@PassportNo, @Address1, @Address2, @Address3, @Address4, @Address5, @CreditType, @UniqueRefID, @BorrowerType, @SectorLoanClass, @DateApproved, @Currency, @AmountOrg, @AmountOut, @AmountDis, @DateUpdate, @AmountInst, @DateFirstInst, @Periodicity, @DateLastInst, @DateExp, @DateRegistered, @NoInst, @EffectiveDate, @BalDefault, @AmountArrs, @NoOfDays, @FirstColl, @SecondColl, @ThirdColl, @ForthColl, @FifthColl, @Remarks, @DateRegularised, @ActionTaken, @ActionDate, @PaymentHistory1, @PaymentHistory2, @PaymentHistory3, @PaymentHistory4, @PaymentHistory5, @PaymentHistory6, @PaymentHistory7, @PaymentHistory8, @PaymentHistory9, @PaymentHistory10, @PaymentHistory11, @PaymentHistory12, @PaymentHistory13, @PaymentHistory14, @PaymentHistory15, @PaymentHistory16, @PaymentHistory17, @PaymentHistory18, @PaymentHistory19, @PaymentHistory20, @PaymentHistory21, @PaymentHistory22, @PaymentHistory23, @PaymentHistory24, @PaymentHistory25, @PaymentHistory26, @PaymentHistory27, @PaymentHistory28, @PaymentHistory29, @PaymentHistory30, @PaymentHistory31, @PaymentHistory32, @PaymentHistory33, @PaymentHistory34, @PaymentHistory35, @PaymentHistory36, @XMLFilePath)

FETCH NEXT FROM XMLFilesCursor INTO @XMLFilePath
END

CLOSE XMLFilesCursor
DEALLOCATE XMLFilesCursor
```

Comment: (1) Please add XML sample to your question. It is possible to simplify significantly your implementation. (2) Also add your SQL Server version `SELECT @@VERSION;`